# How to upload properly in 000webhost using codeigniter for a project

Tags: codeigniter

I think I miss something in the index.php file or something. I'm trying to upload my project in a  zip file named "application.zip" in 000webhost. but there is an error that keeps appearing when I try to access my website. here is the error: "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to upload ```system``` folder also.

Comment: I did upload it

Comment: @Philip - how does your directory tree looks like after extracting zip file? Where are application and system folders and your index.php placed? What system folder path do you have in your index.php?

Comment: Hi I updated my post. In the screenshot above. all folders like application, system folder and the index.php file are inside the zip file. In the index.php file the system folder path is "$system_path = 'system';" for the system folder.

Comment: @Philip : sorry but according to my knowledge, web-server not reading files from zip. Correct me if I am wrong.